# calculating winding number around zero

Tags: complex-analysis, winding-number

let $m, n \in \mathbb{Z}$ be fixed and let $ 0 < r \neq 1$, determine the winding number of the closed curve $\gamma(t) : = e^{imt} + re^{int}$ $\gamma: [0, 2\pi] \to \mathbb{C} \backslash 0$ around zero

so we know that
$w_\gamma (0) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{1}{z-0} dz$
would I then be having

$$w_\gamma (0) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{ime^{imt} + in re^{int}}{e^{imt} + re^{int}} dt$$
?

is my approach correct until now and how could I proceed?

Comment: Observe that $$\frac d{dt}\left(e^{imt}+re^{int}\right)=ime^{imt}+rine^{int}\ldots$$

Comment: @DonAntonio They already knew that, because it came from $dz=(d\gamma)\,dt$

Comment: @FShrike It looks like that was missed as then the way to proceed seems reasonably easy...

Comment: @DonAntonio But the logarithm is subtle on the complex plane. Can we find a holomorphic antiderivative that works on $[0,2\pi)$? I'm not sure

Comment: Well, the argument in $\;[0,2\pi)\;$ is not the usual, standard choice for the main branch of the logarithm, which is $\;(-\pi, \pi)\;$...but it works, too.

Comment: I meant $t\in[0,2\pi)$ as in the OP's integral

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2833452/42969

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm{d}}$Your work is correct. There is probably a slick homotopy theoretic method for this but I don't see it, it's hard for me to visualise this contour.

Let's say $0<r<1$. Then: $$\begin{align}w_{\gamma}(0)&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi }\frac{m+rn\cdot e^{i(n-m)\phi}}{1+r\cdot e^{i(n-m)\phi}}\d\phi\\&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{k\ge0}(-r)^k\int_0^{2\pi}(m+rn\cdot e^{i(n-m)\phi})\cdot e^{ik(n-m)\phi}\d\phi\\&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{k\ge0}(-r)^k\int_0^{2\pi}(me^{ik(n-m)\phi}+rn\cdot e^{i(k+1)(n-m)\phi})\d\phi\\&=m+\sum_{k\ge1}\frac{(-r)^k}{2\pi}\left(m\cdot\int_0^{2\pi}e^{ik(n-m)\phi}\d\phi-n\cdot\int_0^{2\pi}e^{ik(n-m)\phi}\d\phi\right)\\&=m+\sum_{k\ge1}(-r)^k(m\cdot\delta_{n,m}-n\cdot\delta_{n,m})\\&=m-\delta_{n,m}(m-n)\cdot\frac{r}{1+r}\\&=m\end{align}$$

Similarly you can brute-force compute $w_\gamma(0)=n$ if $r>1$. Here I use $\delta_{i,j}$ the Kronecker delta notation. It just means "$0$", if $i\neq j$, and "$1$" if $i=j$. Notice that $\delta_{i,j}\cdot(i-j)$ is *always* zero.

The case $r=1$ should be handled with care, and this is based on Mark Viola's comments.

In light of: $$e^{im\phi}+e^{in\phi}=e^{i(m+n)\phi/2}(e^{i(m-n)\phi/2}+e^{-i(m-n)\phi/2})=2e^{i(m+n)\phi/2}\cos\left(\frac{m-n}{2}\phi\right)$$

And the observation that, whenever $m,n$ are distinct integers, there is at least one integer $k$ with: $$\frac{k+\frac{1}{2}}{m-n}\in[0,1]$$Shows that there is at least one root of $\cos\left(\frac{m-n}{2}\phi\right)$ in the interval $[0,2\pi]$, so our contour passes through the origin and its winding number about the origin is not defined. So the question only becomes sensible if $m=n$, and then we can write: $$\begin{align}w_\gamma(0)&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\left(\frac{m+n}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{e^{i(m-n)\phi/2}+e^{-i(m-n)\phi/2}}{e^{i(m-n)\phi/2}+e^{-i(m-n)\phi/2}}\d\phi\\+\frac{m-n}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{e^{i(m-n)\phi/2}-e^{-i(m-n)\phi/2}}{e^{i(m-n)\phi/2}+e^{-i(m-n)\phi/2}}\d\phi\right)\\&=\frac{n+m}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}(1)\d\phi+0\\&=n=m\end{align}$$

But this is actually obvious, since $\gamma$ is the curve $t\mapsto2e^{int}$.

Comment: And for $r>1$, the winding number is $n$.  And for $r=1$, the winding number is $(n+m)/2$.

Comment: @MarkViola I remarked on $r>1$ case, how did you do $r=1$ case?

Comment: fshrike I'm actually in a noisy public place and doing calculations in my head.  So I might be wrong here.  But for $r=1$, factor out $e^{i(m+n)t/2}$ from numerator and denominator.  The denominator term is $2\cos((m-n)t/2)$.  The numerator has real part $(n+m) \cos((m-n)t/2)$.  Now look at the imaginary part.  It should integrate to $0$.  But there might be a singularity in the denominator.  Proceed with caution my friend.  Let me know if this works or fails.

Comment: @MarkViola I've edited based on your comment.

Comment: A solution using a homotopy argument is e.g. here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2833452/42969 – found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cgamma(t)%20%3A%20%3D%20e%5E%7Bimt%7D%20%2B%20re%5E%7Bint%7D%24%2C%20AND%20content%3Awinding)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler approach that is easy to visualize.  First consider the winding number around zero of
$\sigma(t) = \exp\big(i\cdot t\big)$ for $t\in [0,2\pi]$.  A standard calculation is that $n\big(\sigma,0\big)=1$; finish by using the fact that winding numbers (around zero) of products split into sums of winding numbers. Note this implies $n\big(\sigma^k,0\big)=k$ for $k\in \mathbb Z$.  The original problem reads

$n\big(\gamma,0\big)= n\big(\sigma^m\cdot(1+r\cdot \sigma^{n-m}),0\big)=n\big(\sigma^m,0\big)+n\big(1+r\cdot \sigma^{n-m},0\big)=m+n\big(r\cdot \sigma^{n-m},-1\big)$

**(i)** if $r\lt 1$ then $-1$ is in the unbounded component so $n\big(r\cdot \sigma^{n-m},-1\big)=0\implies n\big(\gamma,0\big)=m$
**(ii)** if $r\gt 1$, then $-1$ is in the same component as zero (they are path connected on the real line) so
$n\big(r\cdot \sigma^{n-m},-1\big)=n\big(r\cdot \sigma^{n-m},0\big)=n\big(\sigma^{n-m},0\big)=n-m\implies n\big(\gamma,0\big)=n$

Comment: And what is the result for $r=1$?

Comment: @MarkViola -- there's two answers here.  First answer: the OP explicitly states that $r\neq 1$ so it is outside the scope.  Second answer: with $r:=1$ the pitfall the OP was trying to avoid becomes geometrically obvious since $n\big(r\cdot \sigma^{n-m},-1\big) =n\big(\sigma^{n-m},-1\big)$ which is not defined (i.e. a walk around the unit circle always hits $-1$) unless $n-m=0$, i.e. the constant curve so $n\big(\sigma^{0},-1\big) = 0\implies n\big(\gamma,0\big) = m + 0$

Comment: First, (+1).  Second, your homage to Tommy Tutone's song is amusing.  Third, you might consider explicitly writing the definitions of $\sigma^k$ and $n(\cdot,\cdot)$  Finally, there is a typographical error.  Using your definition of $\sigma(t)$ as $e^{2it}$ would have a winding number of $2$, not $1$.

Comment: @MarkViola good catch.  I normally do it for $t\in[0,1]$ and changed it last minute to "match" OP.  Now fixed.